# How can I get all selected items for a QListWidget when the user interacts with the list?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

How can i get all the selected items for a QListWidget inside an event handler ("slot") which is activated when the user interacts with the list? In other words i need to have the full list of selected items available when the user preforms an action (like choosing a new selection in the list)

What i've tried so far is using `QListWidget.currentItemChanged` and then trying to get all the selected list items with `QListWidget.selectedItems()` The problem i'm having with this approach is that the list returned from the `selectedItems()` function is not updated until after exiting the event handler that i have connected to `currentItemChanged`

The solution that i'm looking for has to work with "MultiSelection" (multiple list items can be selected at the same time)

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use the `itemSelectionChanged` signal, this is activated when any item is selected.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QApplication, QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.listWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.on_change)

        for i in range(10):
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(str(i))
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

    def on_change(self):
        print("start")
        print([item.text() for item in self.listWidget.selectedItems()])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Output:

```
start
['2']
start
['2', '3']
start
['2', '3', '4']
start
['2', '3', '4', '6']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (I thought that i had tried `itemSelectionChanged` when experimenting with different signals but i must have missed it)

Comment: Duh, I was hitting my head against the desk trying to figure out why `currentItemChanged` kept giving me the LAST selected item (not the new one) only to realize I overlooked `itemSelectionChanged` which seems to fix the problem

Comment: @Spencer a currentItem may or may not be a selected item. :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc Hah, so I learn... It is a bit funny that it would consistently return the previously selected item on a selection change though. I assume there's a logical reason in the docs somewhere.

Comment: @Spencer is correct what you point out, that is, that the last selected element is set as currentItem, but not that all currentItem is a selected item.

Answer (score 0):

## This goes inside of the class where you define the QMainWindow

```
class YourClass(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
       super(YourClass,self).__init__()
       uic.loadUi("Your_Qt_document_name.ui", self)

       #Binding the QListWidget created in the Qt Designer
       self.Your_QListWidget_Name.clicked.connect(self.getListItem)

    #on cLick item method
    def getListItem(self):
       #prints the selected item
       print(self.Your_QListWidget_Name.currentItem().text())
```