# How can I get the ROW NUMBERS for all selected items for a QListWidget when the user interacts with the list?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I found lots of answers for getting the .text() of the listwidget item, but I want the row number....

Seems pretty complicated to get something so simple. I know the row when the user clicks on it, but I don't know how to get all the currently visibly selected rows by row number.

Based on this answer:

[How can I get all selected items for a QListWidget when the user interacts with the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772092/how-can-i-get-all-selected-items-for-a-qlistwidget-when-the-user-interacts-with)

Comment: use  `print([self.listWidget.row(item) for item in self.listWidget.selectedItems()])`

Comment: Thank you kindly! I looked everywhere and it was under my nose.... Especially helpful to get it in Python syntax as the C++ is Confusing++